# How to disable Head Tracking on Mac for AirPods in TV app?

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, airpods, tv.app

I'm watching a show on TV app on Mac with AirPods. It tracks my head position so that the sound appears to come from the laptop. How do I turn it off?

I switched this setting off on my iPhone (Settings > Accessibility > AirPods > Follow iPhone), but the head tracking is still enabled in TV app on my Mac.

I'm using AirPods (3rd gen) with my 2021 M1 Pro MacBook Pro 14". MacOS Monterey 12.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck "Spatial audio follows head movements" in `System Preferences > Accessibility > Audio`.

Note that Spatial audio requires a Mac with Apple Silicon.

###### Sources:

1. [Apple AirPods User Guide: Control spatial audio and dynamic head tracking](https://support.apple.com/guide/airpods/control-spatial-audio-dynamic-head-tracking-dev00eb7e0a3/web)
2. [Apple macOS User Guide: Change Audio preferences for accessibility on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-audio-preferences-for-accessibility-unac611/mac)